# Get dictionary key-value pairs without knowing its type

Tags: c#, reflection, dictionary

I have an object `instance` for which

```
instance.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>)
```

is true. My question is, how can I extract the key-value pairs from this object without actually knowing their generic types? I would like to get something like `KeyValuePair<object, object>[]`. Note that I also know the generic types the dictionary uses at runtime (but not compile-time). I assume some kind of reflection is required?

**FOLLOW-UP:** Is there a general mechanism to convert an `object` to `SomeClass<>` (if I know that is the correct type, of course) and thus use it, given that the implementation of the class is not affected by the type of generic arguments?

Comment: Or the non-generic `IDictionary` interface.

Comment: That's a good point. I am looking for an answer specifically for a `Dictionary<,>` but would like to know if there is a way I can dynamically cast any object that requires generic arguments so that I can use it.

Comment: IDictionary's `ToList` returns a list of KeyValuePairs: `var keyValuePairList = instance.ToList();`.  Is that what your looking for (before your follow-up)?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @steaks I think the problem with that approach is that he has an `object`, and he knows it's some kind of `Dictionary<K,V>`, but he doesn't know what `K` and `V` are.  So he can't call `.ToList()` until he can get his hands on a variable containing the dictionary cast to the correct type, which he'd have to construct at runtime.

Comment: Any reason why you can know that you're getting a dictionary, but can't also use the type system? If you can't know that you're taking a dictionary by the arguments of your function, then you should rethink your design.

Comment: @siride Maybe the dictionaries are stored in something that takes a generic object, such as a Winforms control.  I was just trying to do something similar for generic code to work with some listboxes.  Each of them is populated from a `Dictionary<int, V>` returned by the model, where `V` can vary.  The function that populates the listboxes just takes this dictionary as an `IEnumerable` (such that looping through gives `KeyValuePair`s).  The challenge I faced was in my generic function to get the key of the currently selected item from the listbox.  In the end, `dynamic` worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do what Jeremy Todd said except maybe a little bit shorter:

```
    foreach(var item in (dynamic)instance)
    {
       object key = item.Key;
       object val = item.Value;
    }
```

And as a side note (not sure if helpful), you can get the types of the arguments like this:

```
Type[] genericArguments = instance.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
```

Comment: I would like to add that dynamic can also be used to retrieve the values using indexer syntax: `(myDictonary as dynamic)["someKeyValue"]`

Comment: any idea how to do this without `dynamic`? I'm stuck in .NET 3.5 and `dynamic` wasn't added until 4.0 apparently.

Answer (score 5):

For a quick solution, you could just use `dynamic`:

```
Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

myDictionary.Add("First", 1);
myDictionary.Add("Second", 2);
myDictionary.Add("Third", 3);

dynamic dynamicDictionary = myDictionary;

foreach (var entry in dynamicDictionary)
{
  object key = entry.Key;
  object val = entry.Value;
  ...whatever...
}
```

Comment: There's no way to solve this problem without circumventing the type system, because the type is not known at compile time.  Any solution is going involve something like `dynamic` or reflection, and of the two `dynamic` is far more elegant.

Comment: So a better answer to the question would be - "Just redesign your solution ?". Care to show us your solution ? How do you even know what his problem is exactly ? I hate THOSE type of answers.

Comment: @siride: I agree that I usually would try to avoid using the "dynamic" solution, but I think that was a bit too harsh. As for a scenario, consider what happens if you try to serialize a dictionary. You would need to be able to serialize any type of dictionary -- how would you generalize the solution?

Comment: @NickolayRatchev: that's why we have generics, or interfaces and wrapper classes that take care of type-specific details. Let the type itself serialize itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with to help me out.  It suited my needs at the time...  Maybe it will help someone else out.

```
foreach (var unknown in (dynamic)savedState)
{
  object dKey = unknown.Key;
  object dValue = unknown.Value;

  switch (dKey.GetType().ToString())
  {
    case "System.String":
      //Save the key
      sKey = (string)dKey;

      switch (dValue.GetType().ToString())
      {
        case "System.String":
          //Save the string value
          sValue = (string)dValue;

          break;
        case "System.Int32":
          //Save the int value
          sValue = ((int)dValue).ToString();

          break;
      }

      break;
  }

  //Show the keypair to the global dictionary
  MessageBox.Show("Key:" + sKey + " Value:" + sValue);
}
```