# Which type to use in a DTO for a key/value collection in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, key-value, angular12

I need to create a class for DTOs in my ASP.NET Core 5 based web application which have some basic properties but also a few properties which are not known at compile time. To be able to transfer those properties, I need some way to store them as key/value pairs in the DTOs. My first idea was to simply use a `Dictionary<string, object>`, but it seems like whenever the objects are returned to the frontend, the dictionary is not being serialized at all and simply gets ignored. While I do not know the property name(s) and type(s) at compile time, I am able to get this information at runtime. The frontend of my web application is based on Angular 12.

What would be a good type to use for transferring this data to the frontend?

Comment: How about a dynamic? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16504090/560784

Answer (score 1):

I would try and use [JsonExtensionData], this attribute allows you to store additional properties in an Dictionary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace RoundtripExtensionData
{
    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureCelsius { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        [JsonExtensionData]
        public Dictionary<string, JsonElement> ExtensionData { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string jsonString =
@"{
  ""Date"": ""2019-08-01T00:00:00-07:00"",
  ""temperatureCelsius"": 25,
  ""Summary"": ""Hot"",
  ""SummaryField"": ""Hot"",
  ""DatesAvailable"": [
    ""2019-08-01T00:00:00-07:00"",
    ""2019-08-02T00:00:00-07:00""
  ],
  ""SummaryWords"": [
    ""Cool"",
    ""Windy"",
    ""Humid""
  ]
}";
            WeatherForecast weatherForecast = 
                JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherForecast>(jsonString);

            var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
            jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast, serializeOptions);
            Console.WriteLine($"JSON output:\n{jsonString}\n");
        }
    }
}
// output:
//JSON output:
//{
//  "Date": "2019-08-01T00:00:00-07:00",
//  "TemperatureCelsius": 0,
//  "Summary": "Hot",
//  "temperatureCelsius": 25,
//  "SummaryField": "Hot",
//  "DatesAvailable": [
//    "2019-08-01T00:00:00-07:00",
//    "2019-08-02T00:00:00-07:00"
//  ],
//  "SummaryWords": [
//    "Cool",
//    "Windy",
//    "Humid"
//  ]
//}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-handle-overflow?pivots=dotnet-5-0